# are finished eating./have finished eating

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> Tim and Tom sit at the dinner table eating breakfast.
>
> Mother: *Finish your breakfast. You don't want to be late for school.*
>
> LATER.
>
> Tim and Tom **are/have** finished eating and are ready to go.

Hi. I'm writing a script. Would 'are' and 'have' both work perfectly here or would one of them sound wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Not to be rude, but are you sure you're ready for script writing? I'd use *have* to indicate that a prior action has been completed and to imply that getting ready took up some time.

Comment: Not to be rude, but are you sure you're ready for script writing? I'd use *have* to indicate that a prior action has been completed and to imply that getting ready took up some time.

Comment: We use past participles to construct perfect tenses, the passive voice, and adjectives. So even native speakers have a hard time distinguishing them. "I am finished"—an adjective—works fine to describe a state of things. But the addition of "eating" makes the idea more "verb-like." So I also recommend "have" in this case.

Comment: You don't say where you are. 'Are finished eating' sounds odd in British English.

Comment: Google: "are finished eating" site:.uk Plenty of hits.

Answer (score 1):

The two are both grammatical and idiomatic. In a strict sense, they both describe the same set of facts.

They may, however, indicate slightly different shades of meaning.

> They are finished eating

focuses on the current state with little stress on the preceding activity. The emphasis is on “finished.”

> They have finished eating

is perhaps slightly richer because it put more equal weight on present state and past activity.

I would go with whichever formulation better suits your exact intent. If you want to stress that the activity is over, “are” works better. If you want to stress the recent activity while recognizing that it is now over, “have” works better. Meaning is the ultimate criterion.